# gradlew: build submodule from root directory without loading other submodules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradlew

So my application is split into .aar library (which is published as a CI artifact) and to app itself.

```
|-app/
|--build.gradle
|-lib/
|--build.gradle
|-libs/         // this folder is magically filled with lib.aar by CI server.
|-settings.gradle
|-build.gradle // settings (repository adresses etc)
```

I want to build app from root without deleting `settings.gradle`, however:

- issuing `gradlew -u 'app:assembleDebug'` still scans/loads lib project

How to build `app:assembleDebug` without loading other modules, using `gradlew` as build tool?